# Can't set headers after they are sent getting when inserting dynamic field values in to mysql DB using node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Am trying to insert dynamic fields value using nodejs but the two fields are not storing in the tables am getting the value as undefined, in the server console am getting **Can't set headers after they are sent** how to resolve this error please help, my code is pasted below have a look and correct if any thing is wrong

Node server

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var http=require('http');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var path=require('path');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());       
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
var myconnection = mysql.createConnection({
host : "localhost",

user : "root",

password : "",

database : "siva"
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ""));
var uqid= uuid.v1();
var it_id=uuid.v4();
var tt=1;
var status="active";
app.post("/insert",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    /* TODO: Now just check that your drive function is correct, SQL is correct and whether what arguements passed to SQL callback is correct */
    myconnection.query('Insert into cate_tbl (cat_id,cat_name,cat_desc,cat_view_count,cat_status) VALUES ("'+uqid+'","'+req.body.cat_name+'","'+req.body.cat_desc+'","'+tt+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {
        //if (err) throw err;
        if (err) {console.log("DB Error"+err); res.send("add failed"+err);}
        else res.send("add success");
    });
    //res.send("success");


      myconnection.query('Insert into cate_item (cat_it_id,cat_it_name,cat_pid,cat_it_count,cat_it_desc,cat_it_status) VALUES ("'+it_id+'","'+req.body.item_name+'","'+uqid+'","'+req.body.tem_count+'","'+req.body.item_desc+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {
        //if (err) throw err;
        if (err) {console.log("DB Error"+err); res.send("add failed"+err);
return;
    }
        else res.send("add success");
    });
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send two responses for one API call.That's by you are getting 
**Can't set headers after they are sent**

If you want to fire two query then you can fire first query the response of that query you can fire another query.

try this:

```
    app.post("/insert",function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
        /* TODO: Now just check that your drive function is correct, SQL is correct and whether what arguements passed to SQL callback is correct */
        myconnection.query('Insert into cate_tbl (cat_id,cat_name,cat_desc,cat_view_count,cat_status) VALUES ("'+uqid+'","'+req.body.cat_name+'","'+req.body.cat_desc+'","'+tt+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {
            //if (err) throw err;
            if (err){
                console.log("DB Error"+err); 
                res.send("add cate_tbl failed"+err);
            }else {
               myconnection.query('Insert into cate_item (cat_it_id,cat_it_name,cat_pid,cat_it_count,cat_it_desc,cat_it_status) VALUES ("'+it_id+'","'+req.body.item_name+'","'+uqid+'","'+req.body.tem_count+'","'+req.body.item_desc+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("DB Error"+err);
                        res.send("add cate_item failed"+err);
                    }else{
                        res.send("add success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

> For dynamic a query you can write a function which will take the req.body and generate the dynamic query string and then fire.

```
generateQuery = function(data,tableName){
    var fields = Object.keys(data);

    var values = [];
    for(var o in data) {
        values.push(data[o]);
    }
    return "Insert into "+tableName+"("+fields.join(",")+") values ("+values.join(",")+")"
}

var query = generateQuery(req.body,"tableName");

myconnection.query(query,function(err, results, fields) {
    //your logic.

 });
```

Comment: actually req.body.item_name, req.body.item_desc is not getting the value from the field, am having a dynamic field which is inserted n number of time when user clicks add fields, could you please tell me what will be the error

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav you can create a dynamic query which will generate the dynamic query string and then fire it.

Comment: can you please post some code snippet to understand about the dynamic query in node js, am new to this technology, am creating dynamic fields using angular js and storing it in json object array for ex:  $scope.table = { fields: [] }; am storing the static field value in table and dynamic field values in fields array and passing my table as parameter in ng-click function

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav you can try above generateQuery in my answer.

Comment: am getting ReferenceError: key is not defined

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav that is fields by mistake I wrote key. Try fields.join() instead of key.join()

Comment: in values.joins can I give the values like this "'+it_id+'","'+req.body.item_name+'","'+uqid+'","'+ireq.body.tem_count+'","'+req.body.item_desc+'","'+status+'" or i shoud givewith out quotes and + symbol

Comment: am getting the following error 

[Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object]'32f6635e-309c-4ddf-ac1f-47aecbbbcb52','undefined','985af750-aa42' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav you can't use the double quote you have to use single quote inside double quote "' +req.body.item_name+ '" and so on ...

Comment: thanks fro answering the question, I have cleared that one now am strugling in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464915/how-to-sum-a-dynamic-text-box-value-inside-ng-repeat) if you dont mind can u help in that question please