# How to sum a dynamic text box value inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sum

I am creating a dynamic form fields in which there is only one input type number field inside the ng-repeat, user can add any number of fields by clicking add button, now I need to calculate the sum of values entered in dynamic number field and update in a text box, below I paste my code for your reference, help me to resolve

```
      <fieldset ng-repeat="field in table.fields track by $index" >

 <input type="number" ng-model="table.fields[$index].item_count" class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>

  <button ng-click="removeChoice()" class="remove btn btn-danger" >close</button>
     </fieldset>


      <button class="addfields btn btn-success" ng-click="addFormField()" ng-disabled="!frm.cat_name.$dirty||!frm.cat_desc.$dirty||frm.cat_desc.$invalid||frm.cat_name.$inavalid">Add fields</button>
```

Comment: Don't understood what do you want. In which text box you want to display sum of input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a custom filter to sum your numbers:

```
angular.module('App').filter('mysum', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var sum = 0;
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.item_count) {
         sum += item.item_count;      
      }
    })
    return sum;
  }
})
```

Then use it to display the sum:

```
<span>{{ table.fields | mysum }}</span>
```

Comment: why its not displaying the total when clicked the add button to add more fields, actually the total is getting disappeared when a new field is added after the number is entered it displays the total sum

Comment: thanks a ton its working,one more thing am displaying the total in a text box using ng-model (ng-model="table.fields | mysum") how I can access thistext box in node js like req.body any idea

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav Sorry, no idea about nodejs request.